# Highcharts: x-axis not consistent when using categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to draw a column/bar chart as shown in JSFiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qh17f7ao/1/

Here is my Highcharts data:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [['Jan',49.9], ['Feb', 71.5], ['Mar', 91]]
}, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [['Jan',83.6], ['Feb',78.8], ['Apr',100]]
}, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [['Mar',83.6], ['Jun',78.8], ['Aug',100]]

}, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [['Jan',83.6], ['Apr',78.8], ['Sep',100]]
}]
```

If you take a look at the x-axis categories, I have a broad range of months listed such as Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, Jun, Aug, Sep.

However, when I pass the data to Highcharts for rendering, the axis is not consistent and missing specific data points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much can be said here, but I think this line from [the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cline%3E.data.name) sums it up:

> If the **xAxis.type** is set to category, and no **categories** option exists, the category will be pulled from the `point.name` of the last series defined. For multiple series, best practice however is to define `xAxis.categories`.

My best advice is therefore to do exactly that. Don't use name, use `categories`.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh17f7ao/2/)):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [[0,49.9], [1, 71.5], [2, 91]]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [[0,83.6], [1,78.8], [3,100]]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [[2,83.6], [5,78.8], [7,100]]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [[0,83.6], [3,78.8], [8,100]]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ondkloss, i think this works. Also, there seems to be a gap when a particular data point is missing, do u know if there is a way to close it ?